# How can I simulate m random samples of size n from a given distribution with R?

Tags: r

I know how to generate a random sample of size n from a standard statistical distribution, say exponential. But if I want to generate m such random samples of size n (i.e. m vectors of dimension n) how can I do it?

Comment: `replicate(5, rnorm(3))`

Comment: 1. So you want it in a matrix or a data frame (or maybe a list?) 2. Do you have very large samples?/do you care a great deal how fast it is?

Answer (score 1):

To create a `n` by `m` matrix containing `m` samples of size `n` you can use:

```
x <- replicate(m, rnorm(n, ...))
```

Obviously substituting `rnorm` with other distributions if desired. If you then want to store these in separate individual vectors then you can use

```
v <- x[ , i]
```

This puts the `i`th column of `x` into `v`, which corresponds to the `i`th sample. It may be easier/quicker to just use a simple for loop altogether though:

```
for(i in 1:m){
  name <- paste("V", i, sep = "")
  assign(name, rnorm(n, ...))
}
```

This generates a random sample at each iteration, and for stage `i`, names the sample `Vi`. By the end of it you'll have `m` random samples named `V1`, `V2`, ..., `Vm`.

Comment: This answer is good, except that it seems to encourage the creation of sequentially named vectors. It would be much better to just keep them in the matrix they came in or in a list (if something might be done post-hoc to make them different lengths) than to `assign` them to sequentially named variables that are harder to work with.

Comment: Reiterating @Gregor's point. There's no need to clutter the namespace; an alternative is to do `as.data.frame(replicate(m, rnorm(n)))` to store it as a data set (or even better, `library(data.table); setDF(replicate(m, rnorm(n)))`)

Comment: @MichaelChirico, but in most cases, it's probably best left as a `matrix`, just a `replicate` outputs.

Comment: well... honestly I'd just do `rnorm(m*n)` and add dimensions in that case.